# Subspace of $M(3,\Bbb R)$ true or false questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-rank, nilpotence

Let $W \subset M(3,\Bbb R)$ be a vector subspace such that $\dim W=7$
I need to determine if this statements are true of false:

1. $\exists\: A \in W$ such that $A$ is not null and A is diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$
2. $\exists\: A \in W$ such that $rk(A) = 2$
3. $\exists\: A \in W$ such that $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$
4. $\exists\: A \in W$ such that $A$ is not nilpotent

I'm completely stuck on this problem. I tried to write $A$ in terms of a base of $W$ but I can't go further in any of this points. For the third point I believe I need to demonstrate if exist a nilpotent matrix that is not null but again, I really haven't any ideas. Any hint or even solution would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: For item 1 (assuming it means that $A$ *is* diagaonalizable), you can ask "What's the dimension of the space $D$ of all diagonal (not diagonalizable!) matrices?" Can my subspsace $W$ possibly intersect $D$ in just the null element ?

Comment: It mean A is not null and A is diagonalizable over R. I edited the  question

Comment: @DietrichBurde why can you guarantee that $I_3 \in W$?

Comment: Notably, for two subspaces $U,V$ of $M(3,R)$, we have
$$
\dim(U \cap V) \geq 9 - \dim(U) - \dim(V)
$$

Comment: Of course, the first one now is trivial. If $D$ is the space of all diagonal matrices than $dimD=3$ so $dim(W \cap D) \ge 1$ hence the first is true. What about the other? All the nilpotent matrices aren't a subspace. @Omnomnomnom Shouldn't it be $dim(U \cap V) \ge dim(U) + dim(V) -9$? Thank you both very much!

Comment: The last one is included in the first: $\exists \: A \in W$ such that $A$ is diagonal so it is also not nilpotent. Instead for the third i could pick the subspace of all the strictly upper triangular matrices (which are all nilpotent) and see that exist a not null nilpotent matrix that we know it isn't diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$. Also let $T$ be the subspace of all the upper triangular matrix. $dimT = 6$ so $dim(W \cap T) \ge 4$ hence exists a matrix $A \in W \cap T$ such that $A$ has $2$ pivot. Am I right? If any of you want to put all of of that in an answer i would be glad to accept it.